# Any way to traverse all the non–enumerable properties?

Tags: javascript

When writing JavaScript, I often forget some properties of built-in objects and have to look them up in [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/), which is quite bothering since it slows down my work.

Instead of referring to documents, It is more convenient to create an object and use `for ... in` to inspect it with  `console.log()`. But when it comes to non–enumerable properties, even `for ... in` won't help.

So my question is, besides google and documents, is there any way to inspect non–enumerable properties?

```
for(var i in Object){
    console.log([i,Object[i]]);
    // ["wtbind", function()]
}
console.log(Object.hasOwnProperty('create'));
// true
// Here Object.create is a non–enumerable property,
// and I have to look it up in documents if I forget it.
```

Comment: What browser do you use for development? Have you considered `console.dir()` instead of `console.log()`?

Comment: Does non-enumerable disable the ability to use Object.toSource();?

Comment: @lanzz firefox and firebug. I didn't know there is a `console.dir()`. I tried `console.dir(Object);//shows "prototype Object{}"`, but those non–enumerable properties such as Object.create did not show up.

Comment: @Tar I think the non-enumerable descriptor just disable enumeration on a certain property, and won't do anything to disable `.toSource()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames

seems useful, although it is a rather recent addition and apparently doesn't work in Opera. Although it only lists **own** properties, you can always climb up the prototype chain.

Comment: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object);//["prototype", "getPrototypeOf", "getOwnPropertyDescriptor", "keys", "defineProperty", "defineProperties", "create", "getOwnPropertyNames", "isExtensible", "preventExtensions", "freeze", "isFrozen", "seal", "isSealed", "length", "name", "arguments", "caller"]`, great! And a `for` loop will show their types if I want to know.

Comment: And since I will only use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` in developing environment, eg. firefox and nodeJS, the Opera issue is OK with me. Thank you again.

Comment: @Rufus Ah, OK then :) I, on the other hand, primarily use Opera, so I was not happy to find that out ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but you can use new features for ES6 and I think ES2018 for this:

You can use a `for...of` with the help of an iterator **if** you implement an iterable object (since object are not iterable)

Let's say you have the following object with one enumerable property and on non-enumerable property

```
const obj = Object.defineProperties({}, {
  enumerableKey: {
    enumerable: true,
    value: 'hello'
  },
  nonEnumerableKey: {
    enumerable: false,
    value: 'world'
  }
});
```

You can make it iterable using `Symbol.iterator` and define your own implementation. In the example below, I'm yielding the value of each key (but you can yield whatever you want)

```
obj[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
  for(const key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)) {
    yield this[key]
  }
}
```

After this, you can traverse it with a `for...of` loop:

```
// This will log:
// 'hello'
// 'world'
for(const val of obj) {
  console.log(val);
}
```

Or use the spread operator (since spreading uses iteration via `Symbol.iterator`)

```
[...obj] //[ 'hello', 'world' ]
```

Of you'd like to read more about it, I would recommend you read the following:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax